# Unable to install "tidyverse" in R or Rstudio without running into errors and/or non-zero exit status

Tags: linux, r, rstudio

I've been having troubles with installing the tidyverse package in Rstudio and more recently when reinstalling R. I'll post my most recent error message when reinstalling R below after system info.

My system info to start:
Lenovo Thinkpad T14s Gen 2a
OS:Dual boot with Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3 (una)(kernel 5.13.0-51-generic), and Windows 10 on separate partition.

userXXXX:~$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-tidyverse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-cran-tidyverse : Depends: r-cran-broom but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-dbplyr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-dplyr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-dtplyr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-forcats but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-googledrive but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-googlesheets4 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-ggplot2 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-haven but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-hms but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-httr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-modelr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-readr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-readxl but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-reprex but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-rvest but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-stringr but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-tibble but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-cran-tidyr but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

It seems like I need to remove these broken packages before reinstalling the new ones. If there is anyone that can help with going about this it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!